# Difference between Metonymy and Synecdoche

Tags: figurative-language

"One thousand hands made the pyramids of Egypt." How is the word 'hands' used in the sentence? Is it metonymy or synecdoche?

Comment: Synecdoche is  one form of metonymy. Your example is both.

Comment: To be more specific,  metonymy is using a world related to a noun in place of that noun.  Synecdoche is metonymy where the stand-in is a part or attribute of the replaced noun.  Example of metonymy without synecdoche:  "Do you smoke the pipe?" meaning "do you smoke pipe tobacco?" and  "Buckingham Palace has invited me to tea" meaning "the Queen / residents of Buckingham Palace have invited me to tea."